# Flutter: Adding button shows up behind ListView, "duplicate child" error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a button to navigate to another screen but I'm not sure how to get it on the bottom of my list instead of behind it. This is my current list:

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[800],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: Type.samples.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return BoardingDetail(boarding: Type.samples[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: buildBoardingCard(Type.samples[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And I think this is the code I want to add to navigate to a new screen, I got this code from https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

```
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
```

I tried to integrate the navigation button into my code but it says I have "duplicate child". What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest the ListView and ElevatedButton in a SingleChildScrollView with a Column

You can try running this to see how it is implemented:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "ListView.builder",
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const ListViewBuilder());
  }
}

class ListViewBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListViewBuilder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("ListView.builder")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 8,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                    trailing: const Text(
                      "GFG",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    title: Text("List item $index"));
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Open route'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
          },
          child: const Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]